# What is the standing arch in Nagasaki made of?

Tags: japan

*I am not sure if this is for here, for Skeptics.SE.com or not a serious question at all.* However:

[image]

Comment: Since these pictures don't depict the same torii (or arch) and you can find this as a hoax on the internet by searching for Nagasaki and arch I am closing the question.  True its impressive that the Torii stand but they are typically made of wood or stone or other things, but as gates they can withstand alot of forces due to their design and construction.

Comment: In this light, I guess this is better moved to skeptiks.se. What do you think?

Comment: When I can find this on Google: http://www.hoax-slayer.com/nagasaki-arch-hoax.shtml - there is no need.

Comment: @MichaelF that document is disappointing, as pointed out by the first comment _"That's not really the point, is it? Even if those two arches are from different places, the fact is, both are still standing while all the surrounding houses, buildings and trees get blown to smithereens or washed away by the flood.

What's special about those structures that can withstand tsunamis or atomic bombs?"_